# Lang $SL_2$: fin-dim irreducible subspace for abelian group has dim < 2

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

> **Lang $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ p. 24, Theorem 2** : Let $\pi$ be an irreducible representation of G on a Banach space H. Let $H_n$ be the subspace of vectors v s.t. $$\pi(r(\theta))v = e^{in\theta}v.$$ If dim $H_n$ is finite, then dim $H_n$ = 0 or 1. This is always the case if $\pi$ is unitary irreducible. We know that $H_n$ is irreducible for $\pi^1(S_{n,n})$ and finite dimensional linear algebra shows that dim $H_n = 0$ or 1 since $S_{n,n}$ is commutative.

1) Well I think I have a very simple counter example: let $$\pi\colon \mathbb R \to GL(\mathbb R^2)$$ by $$\theta \mapsto \text{rotation by }\theta.$$ Clearly, $\mathbb R^2$ is an irreducible space for this representation of dim > 1.

The proof goes on:

> On the other hand, if $\pi$ is unitary, and $f\in S_{n,n}$, then $\pi^1(f)^* = \pi^1(f^*)$, where $f^*(x) = f(x^{-1})$. It is immediately verified that $f^*\in S_{n,n}$. Hence, $\pi^1(S_{n,n})$ is *-closed and Schur's lemma implies that dim $H_n$ = 0 or 1.

2) Schur's lemma says that if If M and N are two simple modules over a ring R, then any homomorphism f: M → N of R-modules is either invertible or zero. Here, I understand that simple means irreducible. But why do we need *-closedness? Isn't $\pi^1$ as representation with the structure of a group only already good enough?

Comment: Your citation is not very clear. But probably there is an assumption that you forgot to cite that the base field is algebraically closed.

Comment: The title of the book is exactly this SL_2(R). I agree with you that algebraically closed seems a reasonable assumption. I just double checked, and he didn't mention it. But how would the proof go assuming it?

Comment: The presence of the expression $e^{in\theta}$ would seem to imply that one is working over the complex numbers. For algebras over an algebraically closed field, Schur's lemma says that any linear endomorphism $\phi$ intertwining an irreducible representation is a scalar multiple of the identity, which is proved by showing $\phi-\lambda I=0$ for an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $\phi$. For commutative algebras it implies that the dimension is one, because operators of the algebra intertwine each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) As Marc van Leeuwen already suggested, Lang considers only complex representations, so what you give does not count as a counterexample. (As you say, Lang does not state this assumption explicitly, but I think—besides its being standard in this topic—this is implicit in Ch. I, §2.) How does the proof go now? Just use the fact that a complex finite-dimensional vector space which is irreducible for a commuting family of endomorphisms must have dimension $0$ or $1$.

2) What Lang refers here as Schur's lemma is the one in his Appendix 1, §1. More precisely, one utilizes the corollary on p. 363, and closure under taking adjoints is needed to be able to do so.

Comment: Ow! of course. That's because commuting matrices share the same eigenvalues.